# What is the term Shallow Socket?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I heard the term "Shallow Socket," and I tried to find a definition on internet with no success. Conceptually, Shallow Copy is basically setting a reference of an object to another variable, but I still don't know the exact definition of "Shallow Socket."
Can anybody describe it please?

Comment: Where did you hear the term?

Comment: During a discussion of socket programming. But I am unable to ask from the person so I am asking here.

Comment: I've been doing socket programming since the '90s and I've never heard of a shallow socket until your post -- so I suspect the term might be something specific to a particular API or programming environment that that person was using at the time.

Comment: You're out of your depth here.

Comment: .. or possibly in over your head.

Comment: u must be doing some extra highly technical socket programming ...

Comment: I think so. :/ I think this term is not exist anywhere. The person who told me may be making such type of thing and we have to wait for his release. Topic is over now.

Comment: Finally, I got it.
http://www.javawebdevelop.com/350599/
:)